# Understanding protected in Java

Tags: java, protected, access-modifiers

Some years now that I'm developing in Java and using protected keyword. But I'm now facing a very simple case of protected usage that I don't understand...

Let's say I have a first package, `packagea` with the `Parent` class:

```
package packagea;

public class Parent {

    protected void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("I'm eating");
    }
}
```

And a second package, `packageb`, with a `Child` class:

```
package packageb;

import packagea.Parent;

public class Child extends Parent {

    public void execute(){
        Child child = new Child();
        child.doSomething();

        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.doSomething();   //Will cause java: doSomething() has protected access in packagea.Parent
    }

}
```

If I look at the protected modifier definition for Java, I see :

> Allows access to any subclass or to other classes within the same package.

Why is `parent.doSomething()` not accessible since we are inside `Child` which is a subclass of `Parent`?

Comment: One class is in packagea while childclass is in packageb, so they are not in the same package.

Comment: why would you create those instances? how is the logic of having child extend parent, and then instantiate both child AND parent as local variables in a method of child?
that issue is when you call doSomething on the instance of Parent, and you are not in the same package as Parent. Yes, you are in a subclass, but you are not calling it through an instance of the subclass

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to access `parent.doSomething()` You do have access to the method since you are in a subclass, eg. you can do `super.doSomething()`. You also have access to `child.doSomething()` because it is a protected method, but you're in the same package.

Comment: "Allows access to any subclass or to other classes within the same package." is not *complete*. Java Language Specification [6.6. Access Control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6): "if the member ... is declared protected, then access is permitted only when one ...: * Access to the member or constructor occurs from within the package ... * Access is correct as described in §6.6.2." and "A protected member ... of an object may be accessed from outside the package ... only by code that is responsible for the implementation of that object."